# How to fix broken Ruby commenting in TextMate?

Tags: ruby, textmate, textmate2

Whenever I open a Ruby file in TextMate 2, although it is correctly recognized, the syntax coloring and the commenting are both screwed up.  Instead of <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> putting a `#` at the beginning of all selected lines, I get them wrapped in `/*` and `*/`, as though I was working in JavaScript.

I can live with the broken syntax coloring, but the commenting is driving me crazy, so I want to focus on fixing that in this question (although I won't turn down any solutions that fix both or ignore solutions to the syntax highlighting problem).  I suspect they have the same root cause, so I mention the syntax highlighting in case it provides a valuable clue.

Apparently others have had a similar problem with commenting CSS in TextMate (2) mentioned in "[Textmate "comment" command not working properly for css code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155137/textmate-comment-command-not-working-properly-for-css-code)", but the fixes there didn't help me. There's "[TextMate toggle comment macro is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302785/textmate-toggle-comment-macro-is-broken)" as well, but that has very different symptoms.

TextMate was using my system Ruby (2.0.0 on OS X 10.10), in case that's relevant, but I switched it to using 2.2.3 through rbenv and the problem remains.

Comment: Regarding the close vote: TextMate is definitely on-topic on Stack Overflow as it's a very commonly used tool when programming.

Comment: Sanity check: is TextMate treating your file as Ruby? Does [the bottom bar](http://cl.ly/3H1k2r0S3415/Image%202015-12-21%20at%202.31.23%20PM.png) definitely say Ruby and not JavaScript or something else?

Comment: yes, it recognizes the files as Ruby (and displays "Ruby" in the bottom bar) and the problem remains even after I explicitly set it as Ruby.  The problem goes away if I set it to Crystal, however (which is almost the same as Ruby—but there *are* differences).  The problem is also present if I set the file type to "Ruby on Rails".

Comment: If you press Ctrl + Command + T, and select from the drop down "Key Equivalent" (or press Command + 2), does it list more than one action? Mine shows only one titled "Comment Line" from "Source > Comments".

Comment: Only the one: "Comment Line".  But I looked for "TM_COMMENT_" under settings, and found nothing for Ruby.  Should there be something?  Could my Ruby bundle's settings have gotten deleted somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I started having the exact same problem, **and** I just recently installed this [Crystal bundle](https://github.com/huacnlee/Crystal.tmbundle) the other day. I deleted the bundle and it fixed the problem. I also submitted an issue for that bundle, so, hopefully it gets fixed soon!

Comment: This is now fixed for me! I re-installed the bundle and all is well. :)